# Why do I have to create a separate variable for this to work?

Tags: python-3.x

Why do I need to create a new variable when working out expected rate of return. In the example below?

```
selected = list(my_data.columns[1:]) #Variable holds ['NYTimes','Twitter','Fox']
quarterly_returns = my_data[selected].pct_change()
```

Why cant I access the columns I want and write it like this?

```
quarterly_returns = my_data[1:].pct_change()
```

Is it because I need to drop the datetime and the column headings?

Comment: Because `my_data.columns[1:]` and `my_data[1:]` do not mean the same thing, whatever `my_data` is. Also, `1:` and `list(my_data.columns[1:])` are not the same, so I'm not sure why one would expect them to behave the same

Comment: could you add what `my_data` looks like?

Answer (score 0):

Think I have now found the answer.

The variable holds a list of the column names that we then tell pct.change() to perform the calculation on.